# Obtaining a quadrilateral from four points then splitting it into two triangles

Tags: rendering

Given 4 unordered points, how do I obtain two triangles from those points WITHOUT forming an hourglass shape or having the triangles overlap. Convex quadrilaterals are fine, but I'd prefer a method that would remove the point near the center bounded by the other points within a single triangle. I have a semi-working solution, but it isn't pretty. I have previously tried Delaunay triangulation, forming 4 triangles via a center point and moving around it radially adding points to create triangles, amongst other methods. I cannot seem to find any information of this topic besides splitting triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I did and it seemed to work well. For the first triangle, take the first 3 points and make that a triangle. Then, store a list of the midsections of the points for each edge. The midsection that is closest to the fourth point is on the edge that has the other 2 points that will make your second triangle.

pseudo code

```
func getMidsection(Point a, Point b) -> Point
{
  Point midsection = Point(
   (a.x + b.x) / 2,
   (a.y + b.y) / 2,
   (a.z + b.z) / 2
  );
  return midsection;
}

func getTrianglesFromPoints(Point[4] points) -> Triangle[2]
{
  // define first triangle as first 3 points
  Triangle tri1 = Triangle(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
  
  Point[3] midsections;
  float recordDist = -1;
  int closestMidsection;
  
  // loop through each edge in the first triangle 
  for(i : [0, 3) )
  {
    // get the midsection using the current point and next point in the first triangle
    midsections[i] = getMidsection(points[i], points[(i+1)%3]);
    // if the 4th point's distance to the midsection is smaller than past values, set the smallest dist to that point
    if(dist(points[3], midsections[i]) < recordDist or recordDist == -1)
    {
      recordDist = dist(points[3], midsections[i]);
      closestMidsection = i;
    }
  }
  // define triangle2 from the closest midsection
  Triangle tri2 = Triangle(points[closestMidsection], points[(closestMidsection + 1) % 3, points[3]);

  // return the triangles
  return [tri1, tri2];
}
```